# Artillery gives errors.ECONNREFUSED on Deno Server

Tags: mongodb, load-testing, deno, artillery

I have an simple Deno app, which uses express and Mongodb. **This app works perfect and inserts the record properly when I send request using Postman**.

However, when I run a load test with Artillery, artillery gives error such as:

```
Warning: multiple batches of metrics for period 1696402250000 2023-10-04T06:50:50.000Z
All VUs finished. Total time: 10 seconds

--------------------------------
Summary report @ 09:51:01(+0300)
--------------------------------

errors.ECONNREFUSED: ........................................................... 10
http.request_rate: ............................................................. 1/sec
http.requests: ................................................................. 10
vusers.created: ................................................................ 10
vusers.created_by_name.Register: ............................................... 10
vusers.failed: ................................................................. 10
```

My index.ts:

```
import { MongoClient } from "npm:mongodb";
import express from "npm:express";

const url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/some-db";
const client = new MongoClient(url);
client.connect().then(() => console.log("Connected successfully to server")).catch(console.log("Error connecting to server"));
const db = client.db("some-db");
const collection = db.collection("users");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const savedUser = await collection.insertOne(req.body);

  return res.send(200);
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server is running on 3000'));
```

My artillery file

```
config:
  target: http://localhost:3000
  phases:
    - duration: 10 
      arrivalRate: 1
      name: Warm up the API


scenarios:
  - name: Register
    flow:
      - post:
          url: "/"
          json:
            name: "John"
            surname: "Doe"
            birthday: "1990-01-01"
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the full error message? Static message like **"Error connecting to server"** is not very descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

Some users of Artillery have reported this issue with Deno in the past [here](https://github.com/artilleryio/artillery/issues/1509).

Try changing your target from `http://localhost:3000` to `http://127.0.0.1:3000` and it should resolve it.

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work for me.